# Issue Enabling SSL for Axis2 web services

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to develop secure web service with `SSL/HTTPS`. so I created the server & client keystore file as per ([link](http://all-amit-thinks.blogspot.in/2012/07/enabling-ssl-for-axis2-web-services.html)) and below server & client code but the client code was thrown below exception :

```
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: com.heb.service.WpcimService
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1604)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1597)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:413)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:433)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.heb.client.WpcimClient.main(WpcimClient.java:32)
```

**Server code:**

```
public class SampleWebService {

    public String method(String plainNumericCCNum)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

**Client code:**

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


public class WebServiceClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Wpcim Client");
        try
        {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","d:/client.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");

        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8443/Mywebservice/services/SampleWebService?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://service.client.com", "SampleWebService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        SampleWebService hello = service.getPort(SampleWebService.class);
        System.out.println(hello.method("1234"));

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me to find out, what could be the issue ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Where is `com.heb.service.WpcimService`?

Comment: sorry i renamed the class name to SampleWebService due to audit purpose. so the first one is the one which you asked.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, you need to add the `@WebService` annotation. i.e. your code should look like

```
@WebService(
        portName = "Port name here",
        serviceName = "Service name here",
        targetNamespace = "your tns here")
public class SampleWebService {

    public String method(String plainNumericCCNum)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting below exception When i add above annotation:

HTTP Status 404 - https://localhost:8443/WpcimEncodeDecode/services/WpcimService

type Status report

message https://localhost:8443/WpcimEncodeDecode/services/WpcimService

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

also in below error thrown in client
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://localhost:8443/WpcimEncodeDecode/services/WpcimService?wsdl. It failed with: 
 https://localhost:8443/WpcimEncodeDecode/services/WpcimService?wsdl.

Comment: This is what i added: @WebService( portName = "SampleWebServicePort", serviceName = "service.aaa.com";, targetNamespace = "SampleWebService")

Comment: Can you open the WebService URL in browser?